# How to change alerts

Tags: alert, newsfeed, sitepages

I made a sharepoint group containing around 80 members. I've set some alerts for example: I could set an alert for the newsfeed so I made one for sitepages. So each time something got added on the newsfeed everyone would get a notification.

But everytime someone adds something, everyone gets 2 mails in their inbox. One necessary one with details about the new post but then we get another one, sent before the good one, which contains only this: kso44zji.aspx has been changed (the kso44zji.aspx changes with every post)

How can I make sure the random mail isn't sent? Is it possible to adjust the alert for everyone at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your alerts setting?

Answer (score 0):

The post pages are saved into a Document Library. So, like in every document library, when a document is added two events triggers: added and modified. So you need to set the alert only to sent something on "item modified". This will results in only one e-mail per-event.